# XSD schema namespace issues -- cvc-complex-type.2.4.a

Tags: xml, parsing, jaxb, xsd

I am trying to read an XML file, but he keeps throwing this error:

> - cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>     element 'contact'. One of '{contact}' is expected.
> - lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 68; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the
>     declaration of element 'contacts'.]

I have scoured the web to find answers. If I remove my `targetNamespace`, then it does not complain about finding the elements, but it begins to complain about how it cannot find my custom types declared in the `tns` namespace.

I am validating it here: http://www.corefiling.com/opensource/schemaValidate.html

I am using JAXB to ensure that the document conforms to its schema.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/ContactsSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/ContactsSchema">

    <xs:element name="contacts" type="tns:Contacts" />

    <xs:complexType name="Contacts">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="contact" type="tns:Contact" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Contact">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="address" type="tns:Address" />
            <xs:element name="favorite" type="xs:boolean" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Address">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="state" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="zip" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<contacts xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/ContactsSchema" name="Test">
    <contact id="1">
        <firstName>Herman</firstName>
        <lastName>Munster</lastName>
        <address>
            <street>1313 Mockingbird Lane</street>
            <city>Camelot</city>
            <state>NJ</state>
            <zip>15490</zip>
        </address>
        <favorite>true</favorite>
    </contact>
    <contact id="2">
        <firstName>Al</firstName>
        <lastName>Bundy</lastName>
        <address>
            <street>9764 Jeopardy Lane</street>
            <city>Chicago</city>
            <state>IL</state>
            <zip>60629</zip>
        </address>
        <favorite>false</favorite>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

Comment: contact != tns:contact at a guess

Answer (score 3):

To @Michael's point, you have to put in agreement the targetNamespace of your XSD with that used by your sample XML. Let's assume that the XML is right, and the XSD is wrong... since there are more problems than just the namespace mismatch...

- Your XSD describes the id as an element, while the sample XML shows an attribute.
- Your XSD shows a `firstName` after `lastName`, which is most likely a typo; nonetheless, it needs to be removed to match the XML.

This is a fixed XSD that matches your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.oracle.com/ContactsSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.oracle.com/ContactsSchema">

    <xs:element name="contacts" type="tns:Contacts" />

    <xs:complexType name="Contacts">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="contact" type="tns:Contact" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Contact">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="address" type="tns:Address" />
            <xs:element name="favorite" type="xs:boolean" />
        </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:long"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Address">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="state" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="zip" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion with the id, I originally intended it to be an element in the xml... and for that second firstName, yeah... totally missed that. I did however cheat and use Eclipse's "generate xml from schema" and figured out most of the issues. I assume I needed this in the xml: `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.oracle.com/ContactsSchema ContactsSchema.xsd"`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, regarding the `it begins to complain about how it cannot find my custom types declared in the tns namespace`... setting the default XML namespace (in the XSD file, i.e. xmlns) equal to the targetNamespace, in the schema element... is considered a best practice that relieves you of the need to use a tns, and furthermore, it makes for a much easier way of referencing and reading the XSD...

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is for namespace http://www.example.com/ContactsSchema, but your instance is in namespace http://www.oracle.com/ContactsSchema.